# quality of fit measure

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a list of data {x,y,f(x,y)} with f being an experimental number and x and y are parameters of the experiment. I am using NonlinearModelFit to fit a model function to these data, with a fairly wide range of models available.
In order to distinguish between the various model fits I need a simple to use measure for the goodness of fit. I have tried to read through 'Numerical Operations on Data', but I am overwhelmed by the discussion there. I also know about the possibility to get more infos on the nonlinear fit from nlm["ParameterTable"] and the such. I am no specialist in statistics; all I need is one number, say the chi-squared per degree of freedom, to have a measure for the goodness of fit. How do I get that? What to use?

Comment: _x and y are parameters of the experiment_ is not correct terminology. Those are independent variables. Your parameters are the unknown constants that appear in your model. If you read the documentation for [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) there are five ways given for goodness-of-fit metrics, in particular you'll probably want to start with `"RSquared"`. You can read about the meaning of this value here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Comment: @flinty: the wikipedia article is most helpful; thanks! The Mathematica docu is, on the contrary, not very helpful.

Comment: "I am no specialist in statistics; all I need is one number."  I agree with the first part of your sentence.  Besides the one-number summaries mentioned by @flinty, you'll want to take a look at the residuals to see if the "model" (equation + error structure) actually fits the data. You might want to ask the related question "How do I judge a nonlinear fit to my data?" at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or consult with a statistician.

Comment: If the main objective is to rank competing models on the same data, you should consider obtaining the "AICc" value for each model.  (Then look at the residuals of the top models.)  If the output of `NonlinearModelFit` is named `nlm`, then `nlm["AICc"]` will get you that statistic.  Smaller values are better than larger values.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc.